# pyenchant: check if a given word is a noun (but not a proper noun) and spelled correctly

Tags: pyenchant

python pyenchant library (and so c enchant) allows to check whether a word is spelled correctly
http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/api/enchant.html

```
import enchant
enchant.Dict("en_US").check("house")
```

where does the US dictionary come from?
does it contain also proper nouns, such as Microsoft or John?
is it possible to check if a given word is a noun (but not a proper noun) and spelled correctly?
so, something like:

```
check("house") -> true
check("houses") -> true
check("Microsoft") -> false
check("keiujr") -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

The us_EN dictionary contains words you’d find in a dictionary - so no proper nouns. This means you don’t want to spellcheck capitalized words other than at the beginning of a sentence when spell checking. This isn't ideal, but should work for many cases. It is also possible to add a dictionary of proper nouns to the provided dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nltk and pyspellchecker for this task.
Parts-of-Speech (POS) tagging using nltk can be used to find out what kind of a word it is.

> You can read more about the tags here-https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

Pyspellchecker's unknown function can be used to find out whether or not the given word is spelled correctly.

```
import nltk 
!pip install pyspellchecker
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker()


def check(list_words):
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(list_words) 
for i in range(0,len(tagged)):
    if(tagged[i][1] not in ['NN','NNS']):
        print("False:",tagged[i][0])
    else:
        if(spell.unknown([tagged[i][0]])):
            print("False:",tagged[i][0])
        else:
            print("True:",tagged[i][0])

list_words =['house','houses','Microsoft','keiujr']
check(list_words)
```

> Output for the above code would be.
>
> > True: house
> >
> > True: houses
> >
> > False: Microsoft
> >
> > False: keiujr